# ¿porque pasa se detiene mi juego usando Phaser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

**Hola Developers**, Estaba desarrollando el juago de Space Invaders en una libreria que se llama Pherse.js (JavaScript). Cuando se colisiona dos objetos (bala) vs (enemigo) se congela mi pantalla, led dejo el codigo en JS:

```
JS:

var fondoJuego;
var nave;
var TecladoInputs;
var cursores;
var enemigos;

var balas;
var tiempoBala = 0;
var botonDisparo;
var juego = new Phaser.Game(370 ,550, Phaser.CANVAS, 'bloque_juego2');

var estadoPrincipal = {

preload: function(){
    juego.load.image('fondo2','img/fondito2.jpeg');
    juego.load.image('personaje','img/nave.png');
    juego.load.image('laser','img/laser.png');
    juego.load.image('enemigo','img/enemigos_ovnis.png');

},

create: function(){
    fondoJuego = juego.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 370, 550, 'fondo2');
    nave = juego.add.sprite(juego.width/2,500,'personaje');
    nave.anchor.setTo(0.5);

    //cursores = juego.input.Keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    botonDisparo = juego.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR);

    juego.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
    juego.physics.arcade.enable(nave);
    nave.body.collideWorldBounds = true;

    TecladoInputs = juego.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

    balas = juego.add.group();
    balas.enableBody = true;
    balas.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;
    balas.createMultiple(20, 'laser');
    balas.setAll('anchor.x', 0.5);
    balas.setAll('anchor.y', 1);
    balas.setAll('outOfBoundsKill', true);
    balas.setAll('checkWorldBounds',true); 


    enemigos = juego.add.group();
    enemigos.enableBody = true;
    enemigos.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;

    for(var y = 0; y < 10 ; y++){

        for(var x =0; x < 7; x++) {

            var enemigo = enemigos.create(x*40, y*20, 'enemigo');
            enemigo.anchor.setTo(0.5);
        }
    }
    enemigos.x = 30;
    enemigos.y = 30;
    var animacion = juego.add.tween(enemigos).to({x:100}, 1000,
        Phaser.Easing.Linear.None,true,0,1000,true);
    //var animacion2 = juego.add.tween(enemigos).to({y:500}, 8000,
    //  Phaser.Easing.Linear.None,true,0,1000,true);


    animacion.onLoop.add(descender, this);





},


update: function(){
    //fondoJuego.tilePosition.y +=3;

    ///////////////////////////////////////izquierda
    if (TecladoInputs.left.isDown){
        nave.position.x +=-3;
        fondoJuego.tilePosition.x +=1;

    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////Derecha
    if (TecladoInputs.right.isDown){
        nave.position.x +=3;
        fondoJuego.tilePosition.x +=-1;
    }
    /////////////////////////////////Abajo
    if (TecladoInputs.down.isDown){
        nave.position.y +=3;
    }
    /////////////////////////////////Arriba
    if (TecladoInputs.up.isDown){
        nave.position.y +=-3;
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////Disparo
    var bala;
    if (botonDisparo.isDown){

        if(juego.time.now > tiempoBala){
            bala = balas.getFirstExists(false);
        }
        if (bala){
            bala.reset(nave.x,nave.y);
            bala.body.velocity.y = -350;
            tiempoBala = juego.time.now +200;
        }
    }
    juego.physics.arcade.overlap(balas, enemigos, colision, null, this);

}
};

 function colision(bala, enemigos){
bala.kill();
enemigo.kill();

} 


function descender(){
alert("kpdo");
enemigos.y += 100;
}

juego.state.add('principal2',estadoPrincipal);
juego.state.start('principal2');

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="phaser.js"></script>
<script src="principal2.js"></script>
<title>Juegito</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bloque_juego2">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

*les Dejo el Archivo completo en Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B3Gvh3M7QoaVNGU3S3djVGtEWHc?usp=sharing*

Comment: Hola @Anza. Bienvenida a [es.so]. ¿Podrías comentar qué intentaste para depurarlo? La idea no es publicar todo el código esperando que alguien lo resuelva en tu lugar, sino generar un [mcve] apuntando específicamente a donde estás teniendo problemas. Quizás te interese realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]

Comment: Gracias. pasare por los enlaces que me otorgas.

Comment: ¿Conseguiste averiguar como detectar colisiones entre objetos en Javascript finalmente?